# Want to add filename to a list in Streamlit then convert to dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, pdf, streamlit

I want to add the filename to the following dataframe but my code isn't working:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import streamlit as st
from tabula.io import read_pdf
import os
import glob

# Title
st.title('PDF to Excel')

files = st.file_uploader('Upload all orders',accept_multiple_files=True)

if files:
    for file in files:
        file.seek(0)

    files_read = [read_pdf(file,pages='all')[0] for file in files]
    
    st.write(type(files_read))

    df = pd.concat(files_read)

    df["PO"] = file.name
```

It only adds the first file's name (there are two files in this instance).

Any help please?

[Picture here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dcmtQ.png)

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out eventually!

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import streamlit as st
from tabula.io import read_pdf
import os
import glob

# Title
st.title('PDF to Excel')

files = st.file_uploader('Upload all orders',accept_multiple_files=True)

if files:
    for file in files:
        st.write("Filename: ", file.name)
        filenames = [file.name for file in files]
        file.seek(0)
        

    files_read = [read_pdf(file,pages='all')[0] for file in files]
    for dataframe, filename in zip(files_read,filenames):
        dataframe['filename'] = filename
    st.write(type(files_read))

    df = pd.concat(files_read)
```